# Adding the code for ascending order of user input

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class searchSorting 
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        String line;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input Number 1: " );
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input Number 2: ");
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input Number 3: " );
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input Number 4: ");
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input Number 5: " );
        line = in.nextLine();
    }
    public static void sortAscending (double[]arr)
    {
        Arrays.sort(arr); 
        System.out.printf("Sorted arr[] = %s", 
        Arrays.toString(arr)); 

}}
```

I am stuck on what the code is for putting the what the user inputs in ascending order. I have looked up and tried multiple resources on ascending order but nothing seems to work. I tried:

```
System.out.print("Input number 1: "+(i+1+":");
```

to try and add the inputs instead of writing all of them out but i was an unknown variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array to store input and a loop to read input.

```
System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
int num = in.nextInt();
double[] arr = new double[num];
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
   arr[i] = in.nextDouble();
}
sortAscending(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array. Then put the stuff you are reading into the array and after that call your method.

```
System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
int amount = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
double[] values = new double[amount];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Input Number " + i + ": ");
    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
}

sortAscending(values);
```

---

Note that the name `sortAscending` is not accurate, it is not just sorting (and then returning the result or in-place), but also printing. So maybe you should rename it to `sortAndPrintAscending`. Or just sort it and let your `main` method to the printing.

Or drop it completely, the method does not really serve any purpose as it is just calling `Arrays.sort`, might as well do that in `main`:

```
System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
int amount = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
double[] values = new double[amount];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Input Number " + i + ": ");
    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
}

Arrays.sort(values);
System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(values));
```

Comment: @kayaruth Thanks, corrected. But for real, those errors are really very small. You could have figured that out yourself by reading and **understanding** the code. Or is something unclear still?